# Showing that $|P|$ divides $|A|!$ where $P$ is a $p$-group and $A$ is maximal abelian normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'd appreciate verification of the following proof.  This is the part following what I asked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638875/let-a-be-maximal-among-abelian-normal-subgroups-of-a-p-group-and-show-that) question.  Thanks.

If $A$ is as in the linked-to question above (that is, $A$ is maximal among normal abelian subgroups of a $p$-group $P$, which implies that $A=C_P(A)$), show that $|P|$ divides $|A|!$.

Let $A$ be as described above.  Since $A \triangleleft P$ and $A=C_P(A)$, $N_P(A)/C_P(A)=P/A$ and by the "$N/C$ Theorem", $P/A \cong H$ for some $H \le \mathrm{Aut}(A)$.  It follows that $\frac{|P|}{|A|}$ divides $|\mathrm{Aut}(A)|$, which divides $|S_{|A|}|$, where $S_{|A|}$ is the symmetry group acting on the elements of $A$.  Also, we clearly have that $|A|$ divides $|S_{|A|}|=|A|!$.  It follows that $|P|=\frac{|P|}{|A|}|A|$ divides $|\mathrm{Aut}(A)||A|$ which divides $|S_{|A|}|=|A|!$, so we have $|P|$ divides $|A|!$.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: This doesn't look fine: you've shown that $|P|$ divides $|A|!|A|$, but this doesn't imply $|P|$ divides $|A|!$. Also, in your linked post, you have 3 (!) complete answers to your question (including ones from me and @DonAntonio), but it is still marked as unanswered...

Comment: @user115654 I have chosen an answer to the other question now so the question doesn't get bumped back to the top, but I had not initially because I felt I had received complete solutions to the problem and not hints, as I specified.  I really appreciate receiving useful hints (and always say this in my questions) so I can work through it myself and have that much more opportunity to learn from the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $Aut(A)$ acts faithfully on the set of non-identity elements of $A$, hence $|Aut(A)|$ divides $(|A|-1)!$.

Comment: Upon reading through my attempted proof again I realized that was my problem.  $|A|$ divides $|A|!$ so I really need to show that $|\mathrm{Aut}(A)|$ divides $(|A|-1)!$.  I can easily see that now thanks to your hint.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok Alex you are welcome! And if uou deem my answer as the right one, please tick it as such.

Comment: Yes, I'll happily choose your answer.  I normally do choose an answer for my questions, but see my comment above.

Comment: Alex, perfect, and keep asking questions to further improve your knowledge!